# Java Error: The constructor is undefined (2)

Tags: java, oop, constructor

Problem: My overloading constructors are undefined, even though I'm doing the right thing (I think so?).

The source code:

```
class Book { 
    String section;
    float subject2;
    char section2, author;
    int subject, author2, year;

Book(String section, int subject, char author, int author2, int year) { 
    this.section = section;
    this.subject = subject;
    this.author = author;
    this.author2 = author2;
    this.year = year;
}
Book(char section2, float subject2, char author, int author2, int year) {
    this.section2 = section2;
    this.subject2 = subject2;
    this.author = author;
    this.author2 = author2;
    this.year = year;
}
void displayData() {
    System.out.println(section + subject + " ." + author + author2 + " " + year);
}
void displayData2() {
    System.out.println(section2 + subject2 + " ." + author + author2 + " " + year);
}}
public class TestBook {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Book book1 = new Book("LB", 2395, "C", 65, 1991);
    Book book2 = new Book("E", 185.86, "P", 277, 2010);
    book1.displayData();
    book2.displayData2();
    s.close();  
}}
```

Apologies for the length if it bothers. Thanks for helping in advanced!

Comment: `"C"` is a `String` , `'C'` is a `char` .

Comment: Oh, I didn't noticed it but thanks, still. "Small help makes big difference."

Comment: I assume this is really just "throw away exercise code", but still: use **meaningful** names in your code, especially for the fields of your classes. You see, section vs section2, what is the sense of that? In other words: when writing code, also practice that "how to come up with good names" part.

Comment: Not trying to be rude but, I'm still a learning student, sir. I haven't been on the part where I also have to worry my naming conventions. However, I am somewhat interested what you mean by "meaningful". What sort of names can come up from someone who has already an expertise in this field?

Answer (score 3):

When you call :

```java
Book book2 = new Book("E", 185.86, "P", 277, 2010);
```

Change "E" to 'E' if you want to call the second constructor with char, otherwise "E" is the String object. Same thing for the field `author` (change "P" to 'P')

By the way, instead of creating `displayData()` method, you can override the `toString()` method :

```java
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "your string with information";
}
```

so you can call this method with :

```java
System.out.println(book.toString());
System.out.println(book); // The same thing ! It will call the toString() method
```